# iOS Swift - Merge and convert .wav files to .mp3

Tags: ios, swift, audio, mp3, lame

I want to merge two or more .wav files to one and then convert it to .mp3 and this I would like to done in Swift (or at least to have option to include it to swift project).

Merge two .wav files in swift isn't problem. [Here is my example](http://pastebin.com/Bx74B90K) Now I don't know how to add lame library to swift project and how to use it (how to change objective c lame code usage syntax to use it in swift).

I stuck in swift so I tried Lame library with Objective C. I found example code for converting .caf to .mp3 so I tried it. Here is what I've tried:

```
- (void) toMp3
{
    NSString *cafFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"caf"];

    NSString *mp3FileName = @"Mp3File";
    mp3FileName = [mp3FileName stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"];
    NSString *mp3FilePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:mp3FileName];

    NSLog(@"%@", mp3FilePath);

    @try {
        int read, write;

        FILE *pcm = fopen([cafFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "rb");  //source
        fseek(pcm, 4*1024, SEEK_CUR);                                   //skip file header
        FILE *mp3 = fopen([mp3FilePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "wb");  //output

        const int PCM_SIZE = 8192;
        const int MP3_SIZE = 8192;
        short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
        unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

        lame_t lame = lame_init();
        lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 44100);
        lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_default);
        lame_init_params(lame);

        do {
            read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2*sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
            if (read == 0)
                write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
            else
                write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);

            fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);

        } while (read != 0);

        lame_close(lame);
        fclose(mp3);
        fclose(pcm);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[exception description]);
    }
    @finally {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(convertMp3Finish)
                               withObject:nil
                            waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}

- (void) convertMp3Finish
{
}
```

But result of this is just .mp3 with noise.

- [Here is example .caf file](http://filebin.ca/28ouwSJYgW4Q).
- [And here is result .mp3 file](http://filebin.ca/28ovMMzLlshA).

So I need fix my three problems:

- Create correct mp3 from caf in Objective C
- Change code to use it for wav file
- And change it to be able to use it in Swift

I know that there are many questions about encoding and converting mp3 in iOS but I can't find one with Swift example and I can't find example with working Objective C code (just code above). Thanks for help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would like to post my working solution because I get so many thumbs up and answer from naresh doesn't help me much.

1. I have generated lame.framework library from this project https://github.com/wuqiong/mp3lame-for-iOS
2. I've added library to my Swift project (Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries)
3. I've created wrapper for using c functions in Objective C and by bridging header I use it in Swift.
4. For concatenate wav files I use AVAssetExportSession with Swift

And now source codes. So first wrapper. It's class for converting .wav files to .mp3. There could be many changes (maybe parameter for output file and other options) but I think everyone could change it. I guess this could be rewritten to Swift but I wasn't sure how to do it. So it's Objective C class:

```
#import "AudioWrapper.h"
#import "lame/lame.h"

@implementation AudioWrapper

+ (void)convertFromWavToMp3:(NSString *)filePath {


    NSString *mp3FileName = @"Mp3File";
    mp3FileName = [mp3FileName stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"];
    NSString *mp3FilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:mp3FileName];

    NSLog(@"%@", mp3FilePath);

    @try {
        int read, write;

        FILE *pcm = fopen([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "rb");  //source
        fseek(pcm, 4*1024, SEEK_CUR);                                   //skip file header
        FILE *mp3 = fopen([mp3FilePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "wb");  //output

        const int PCM_SIZE = 8192;
        const int MP3_SIZE = 8192;
        short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
        unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

        lame_t lame = lame_init();
        lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 44100);
        lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_default);
        lame_init_params(lame);

        do {
            read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2*sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
            if (read == 0)
                write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
            else
                write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);

            fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);

        } while (read != 0);

        lame_close(lame);
        fclose(mp3);
        fclose(pcm);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[exception description]);
    }
    @finally {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(convertMp3Finish)
                               withObject:nil
                            waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Swift AudioHelper class for concatening audio files and calling method for converting .wav file to .mp3:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


protocol AudioHelperDelegate {
    func assetExportSessionDidFinishExport(session: AVAssetExportSession, outputUrl: NSURL)
}

class AudioHelper: NSObject {

    var delegate: AudioHelperDelegate?

    func concatenate(audioUrls: [NSURL]) {

        //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
        var composition = AVMutableComposition()
        var compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

        //create new file to receive data
        var documentDirectoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as! NSURL
        var fileDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("resultmerge.wav"))
        println(fileDestinationUrl)

        StorageManager.sharedInstance.deleteFileAtPath(NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("resultmerge.wav"))

        var avAssets: [AVURLAsset] = []
        var assetTracks: [AVAssetTrack] = []
        var durations: [CMTime] = []
        var timeRanges: [CMTimeRange] = []

        var insertTime = kCMTimeZero

        for audioUrl in audioUrls {
            let avAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: audioUrl, options: nil)
            avAssets.append(avAsset)

            let assetTrack = avAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] as! AVAssetTrack
            assetTracks.append(assetTrack)

            let duration = assetTrack.timeRange.duration
            durations.append(duration)

            let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration)
            timeRanges.append(timeRange)

            compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: assetTrack, atTime: insertTime, error: nil)
            insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration)
        }

        //AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough => concatenation
        var assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
        assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeWAVE
        assetExport.outputURL = fileDestinationUrl
        assetExport.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
            self.delegate?.assetExportSessionDidFinishExport(assetExport, outputUrl: fileDestinationUrl!)
        })
    }

    func exportTempWavAsMp3() {

        let wavFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("resultmerge.wav")
        AudioWrapper.convertFromWavToMp3(wavFilePath)
    }
}
```

Bridging header contains:

```
#import "lame/lame.h"
#import "AudioWrapper.h"
```

Comment: Where is the method convertMp3Finish() that's called inside of AudioWrapper?

Comment: It is called in Objective-C Bridged file because the library is done with Objective-C

Answer (score 6):

We have dedicated classes to read/write media from/to a file they are `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetWriter` and with the help of `AVAssetExportSession` you can export it as mp3 file.
or else you can use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter

Comment: My problem with your answer is that when I tried `AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3` as `outputFileType` with `AVAssetExportSession` I get exception `Invalid output file type`. I guess I need mp3 files at start to be able export them to mp3. Second solution with library is not exporting to mp3 or I didn't find any information about that. It converts audio files to .m4a.