# How to Convert .caf file to .mp3 file?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audio-recording

I have record some voice in to the Document Folder using following methods

```
 func record() {
    self.prepareToRecord()
    if let recorder = self.audioRecorder {
        recorder.record()
    }
}

    let recordSettings = [
    AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless)),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 2),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue)),
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(320000))
]

    func prepareToRecord() {

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let soundFileURL: NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("\(documentsPath)/recording.caf")
    print("\(soundFileURL)")

    self.audioRecorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL!, settings: recordSettings)

    if let recorder = self.audioRecorder {
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
    }
}
```

This method will save the audio file as recording.caf in to the Document Directory, but I want to convert this recording.caf file in to mp3 for further manipulation.

How to convert this .caf file to .mp3 in swift ?

Comment: apple does not support mp3,why dont you save it as .mp4?It will audio only

Answer (score 4):

mp3 codec is not supported by AVAudioRecorder because of royalty 
The list of available codecs:

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
kAudioFormatAppleLossless
kAudioFormatAppleIMA4
kAudioFormatiLBC
kAudioFormatULaw
kAudioFormatLinearPCM

You can find the details here [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

Answer (score -1):

You would need to make use of the [Lame Encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Here is the stack overflow link which explains how to do this in swift.

[wav to mp3 in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452202/ios-swift-merge-and-convert-wav-files-to-mp3)