# iOS Code to Convert m4a to WAV

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, file-conversion

Does anyone have any code snippets that show how to convert an M4a file to WAV?  I know there are libraries that convert the other way around.

Thanks.

Comment: see this once may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452202/ios-swift-merge-and-convert-wav-files-to-mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else needs some code to do this here it is in Swift

```
func convertAudioFile(sourceURL: CFURLRef, destinationURL: 
CFURLRef, outputFormat: OSType , 
outputSampleRate: Float64) ->  OSStatus
{
var error : OSStatus = noErr
var destinationFile : ExtAudioFileRef = nil
var sourceFile : ExtAudioFileRef = nil

var srcFormat : AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
var dstFormat : AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()

var audioConverter : AudioConverterRef = nil

audioConverter = AudioConverterRef.init()

ExtAudioFileOpenURL(sourceURL, &sourceFile)

var thePropertySize: UInt32 = UInt32(strideofValue(srcFormat))

ExtAudioFileGetProperty(sourceFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &thePropertySize, &srcFormat)

dstFormat.mSampleRate = (outputSampleRate == 0 ? srcFormat.mSampleRate : outputSampleRate)  //Set sample rate

dstFormat.mFormatID = outputFormat
dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
dstFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16
dstFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
dstFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1
dstFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger // little-endian

//Create destination file
ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL, kAudioFileCAFType, &dstFormat, nil,
    AudioFileFlags.EraseFile.rawValue, &destinationFile)

ExtAudioFileSetProperty(sourceFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, thePropertySize, &dstFormat)
ExtAudioFileSetProperty(destinationFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, thePropertySize, &dstFormat)

var size : UInt32 = UInt32(strideofValue(audioConverter))

ExtAudioFileGetProperty(destinationFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_AudioConverter, &size, &audioConverter)

var canResume : UInt32 = 0

size = UInt32(strideofValue(canResume))

error = AudioConverterGetProperty(audioConverter, kAudioConverterPropertyCanResumeFromInterruption, &size, &canResume)

let bufferByteSize : UInt32 = 32768
var srcBuffer = [UInt8](count: 32768, repeatedValue: 0)

var sourceFrameOffset : ULONG = 0

print("Converting audio file")

while(true){

    var fillBufList = AudioBufferList(
        mNumberBuffers: 1,
        mBuffers: AudioBuffer(
            mNumberChannels: 2,
            mDataByteSize: UInt32(srcBuffer.count),
            mData: &srcBuffer
        )  
    )

    var numFrames : UInt32 = 0

    if(dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame > 0){
        numFrames = bufferByteSize / dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame
    }

    ExtAudioFileRead(sourceFile, &numFrames, &fillBufList)

    if(numFrames == 0){
        error = noErr;
        break;
    }

    sourceFrameOffset += numFrames

    error = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile, numFrames, &fillBufList)
}

ExtAudioFileDispose(destinationFile)
ExtAudioFileDispose(sourceFile)

let audioAsset = AVURLAsset.init(URL: destinationURL, options: nil)
if(audioAsset.duration.seconds < 5.0){
    error = -2500
}

return error;
```

Comment: Which `OSType` and `outputSampleRate` should I pass if I want to convert a m4a file to a wav one?

Comment: Yes.  you want to use OSType of kAudioFormatLinearPCM  and the outputSampleRate of 16000

Comment: Very old code, there is a lot of changes for Swift 3.

Comment: I'll leave that to someone else to update to Swift 3

Comment: **Swift 3** for `AIFF` format at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41437453/218152

Comment: Old code.. This one Got working without AudioConverterRef in swift 5 check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65522764/4524195

Answer (score 12):

Just to update for Swift 3:

```
func convertAudio(_ url: URL, outputURL: URL) {
    var error : OSStatus = noErr
    var destinationFile: ExtAudioFileRef? = nil
    var sourceFile : ExtAudioFileRef? = nil

    var srcFormat : AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
    var dstFormat : AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()

    ExtAudioFileOpenURL(url as CFURL, &sourceFile)

    var thePropertySize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: srcFormat))

    ExtAudioFileGetProperty(sourceFile!,
                            kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat,
                            &thePropertySize, &srcFormat)

    dstFormat.mSampleRate = 44100  //Set sample rate
    dstFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
    dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
    dstFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16
    dstFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
    dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
    dstFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1
    dstFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked |
    kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger

    // Create destination file
    error = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(
        outputURL as CFURL,
        kAudioFileWAVEType,
        &dstFormat,
        nil,
        AudioFileFlags.eraseFile.rawValue,
        &destinationFile)
    print("Error 1 in convertAudio: \(error.description)")

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(sourceFile!,
                                    kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                    thePropertySize,
                                    &dstFormat)
    print("Error 2 in convertAudio: \(error.description)")

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(destinationFile!,
                                    kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                    thePropertySize,
                                    &dstFormat)
    print("Error 3 in convertAudio: \(error.description)")

    let bufferByteSize : UInt32 = 32768
    var srcBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 32768)
    var sourceFrameOffset : ULONG = 0

    while(true){
        var fillBufList = AudioBufferList(
            mNumberBuffers: 1,
            mBuffers: AudioBuffer(
                mNumberChannels: 2,
                mDataByteSize: UInt32(srcBuffer.count),
                mData: &srcBuffer
            )
        )
        var numFrames : UInt32 = 0

        if(dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame > 0){
            numFrames = bufferByteSize / dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame
        }

        error = ExtAudioFileRead(sourceFile!, &numFrames, &fillBufList)
        print("Error 4 in convertAudio: \(error.description)")

        if(numFrames == 0){
            error = noErr;
            break;
        }

        sourceFrameOffset += numFrames
        error = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile!, numFrames, &fillBufList)
        print("Error 5 in convertAudio: \(error.description)")
    }

    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(destinationFile!)
    print("Error 6 in convertAudio: \(error.description)")
    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(sourceFile!)
    print("Error 7 in convertAudio: \(error.description)")
}
```

Comment: Is there any other changes to export to MP3 other than using kAudioFileMP3Type? I'm getting a a nil crash on error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(destinationFile!, when using MP3 type

Comment: You may need to try a different mFormatFlags. You'll noticed that that was a difference between this one and the accepted answer other than kAudioFileMP3Type.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an Objective-C version of MScottWaller's Swift 3 answer.  You need to @import AudioToolbox.

```
-(void) convertAudio:(NSURL*)url outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
{
    OSStatus error = noErr;
    ExtAudioFileRef destinationFile = nil;
    ExtAudioFileRef sourceFile = nil;

    AudioStreamBasicDescription srcFormat;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription dstFormat;

    ExtAudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &sourceFile);


    UInt32 thePropertySize = sizeof(srcFormat); //UInt32(MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: srcFormat));;
    ExtAudioFileGetProperty(sourceFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &thePropertySize, &srcFormat);

    dstFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;  //Set sample rate
    dstFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    dstFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    dstFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    dstFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    dstFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;

    // Create destination file
    error = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(
                                      (__bridge CFURLRef)outputURL,
                                      kAudioFileWAVEType,
                                      &dstFormat,
                                      nil,
                                      kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                      &destinationFile);
    NSLog(@"Error 1 in convertAudio: %d - %@", error, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:error userInfo:nil].description);

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(sourceFile,
                                    kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                    thePropertySize,
                                    &dstFormat);
    NSLog(@"Error 2 in convertAudio: %d - %@", error, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:error userInfo:nil].description);

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(destinationFile,
                                    kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                    thePropertySize,
                                    &dstFormat);
    NSLog(@"Error 3 in convertAudio: %d - %@", error, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:error userInfo:nil].description);

    const UInt32 bufferByteSize = 32768;
    UInt8 srcBuffer[bufferByteSize];// = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 32768)
    memset(srcBuffer, 0, bufferByteSize);
    unsigned long sourceFrameOffset = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        AudioBufferList fillBufList;
        fillBufList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        fillBufList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 2;
        fillBufList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = bufferByteSize;
        fillBufList.mBuffers[0].mData = &srcBuffer;

        UInt32 numFrames = 0;

        if(dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame > 0){
            numFrames = bufferByteSize / dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
        }

        error = ExtAudioFileRead(sourceFile, &numFrames, &fillBufList);
        NSLog(@"Error 4 in convertAudio: %d - %@", error, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:error userInfo:nil].description);

        if(numFrames == 0)
        {
            error = noErr;
            break;
        }

        sourceFrameOffset += numFrames;
        error = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile, numFrames, &fillBufList);
        NSLog(@"Error 5 in convertAudio: %d - %@", error, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:error userInfo:nil].description);
    }

    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(destinationFile);
    NSLog(@"Error 6 in convertAudio: %d - %@", error, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:error userInfo:nil].description);
    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(sourceFile);
    NSLog(@"Error 7 in convertAudio: %d - %@", error, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:error userInfo:nil].description);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to convert m4a to Wav format in Swift 5.

All the above codes are outdated and was not working.
After few tweaks done and here is the working example

```
func convertAudio(_ url: URL, outputURL: URL) {
    var error : OSStatus = noErr
    var destinationFile : ExtAudioFileRef? = nil
    var sourceFile : ExtAudioFileRef? = nil

    var srcFormat : AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
    var dstFormat : AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()

    ExtAudioFileOpenURL(url as CFURL, &sourceFile)

    var thePropertySize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: srcFormat))

    ExtAudioFileGetProperty(sourceFile!,
        kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat,
        &thePropertySize, &srcFormat)
    
    dstFormat.mSampleRate = 44100  //Set sample rate
    dstFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
    dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
    dstFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16
    dstFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
    dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
    dstFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1
    dstFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked |
    kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger


    // Create destination file
    error = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(
        outputURL as CFURL,
        kAudioFileWAVEType,
        &dstFormat,
        nil,
        AudioFileFlags.eraseFile.rawValue,
        &destinationFile)
    reportError(error: error)

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(sourceFile!,
            kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
            thePropertySize,
            &dstFormat)
    reportError(error: error)

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(destinationFile!,
                                     kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                    thePropertySize,
                                    &dstFormat)
    reportError(error: error)

    let bufferByteSize : UInt32 = 32768
    var srcBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 32768)
    var sourceFrameOffset : ULONG = 0

    while(true){
        var fillBufList = AudioBufferList(
            mNumberBuffers: 1,
            mBuffers: AudioBuffer(
                mNumberChannels: 2,
                mDataByteSize: UInt32(srcBuffer.count),
                mData: &srcBuffer
            )
        )
        var numFrames : UInt32 = 0

        if(dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame > 0){
            numFrames = bufferByteSize / dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame
        }

        error = ExtAudioFileRead(sourceFile!, &numFrames, &fillBufList)
        reportError(error: error)

        if(numFrames == 0){
            error = noErr;
            break;
        }
        
        sourceFrameOffset += numFrames
        error = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile!, numFrames, &fillBufList)
        reportError(error: error)
    }
    
    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(destinationFile!)
    reportError(error: error)
    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(sourceFile!)
    reportError(error: error)
}

func reportError(error: OSStatus) {
    // Handle error
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter in the AVFoundation framework can be used read AAC files and write that data as WAV/RIFF files on iOS devices.  There's sample code on the Apple developer site.  It's a bit more than a short snippet.

Comment: Thanks use that's what I'm working through right now.  I'm converting the code to Swift since that sample code is using C++.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edit to @O2U answere. As above code does not actually convert it to wave file. Please use "kAudioFileWAVEType" instead of "kAudioFileCAFType" in above code at line `//Create destination file
ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL, kAudioFileCAFType, &dstFormat, nil,
    AudioFileFlags.EraseFile.rawValue, &destinationFile)`

Comment: Did you change anything else? Is not setting the destinationFile when I use `kAudioFileWAVEType`

Comment: No , haven't change anything else than this. Please check your destination url is correct or not, that may be the issue in case destination file is not set.

Comment: @MarcosGriselli Got it working. while changing to **kAudioFileWAVEType** you have to add  respective flags also **kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked**. Check This https://stackoverflow.com/a/65522764/4524195

Answer (score -3):

I simply changed the extension of the file to .wav and removed the .m4a file and it worked.

```
func getDirectory() -> URL {
    let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = path[0]
    return documentDirectory
}

let date = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

fileName = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(date).m4a")
wavFileName = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(date).wav")

try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileName, to: wavFileName)
try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileName)
```

I even played .wav file and it's working fine.

```
audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: wavFileName)
audioPlayer.play()
```

Are there any drawbacks for converting the file extension from .m4a to .wav like this?

Comment: I am actually interested in knowing about the drawbacks too. I always change file extensions and don't see any consequences. Maybe the one who downvoted your answer would care to explain?

Comment: Yeah I also don't see any drawbacks, can you upvote it?