# Initialize an AudioConverterRef Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, reference, swift3, avfoundation, opaque-pointers

```
var audioConverter : AudioConverterRef = nil
audioConverter = AudioConverterRef.init()
```

So basically I have the code above found from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738133/ios-code-to-convert-m4a-to-wav) that is using a previous version of Swift. Now in Swift 3.0 however the above initializer for `AudioConverterRef` is not available.

I noticed that the `AudioConverterRef` is a reference to an audio converter object, which I suppose is an `AVAudioConverter`.

So, the short question would be how would I write the above code in Swift 3.0? And the longer question would be what are the uses of creating an `AudioConverterRef` that just references an `AVAudioConverter`? Aren't all variables just reference to an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, `AudioConverterRef` was just a typealias of `COpaquePointer` in Swift 2.x and is a typealias of `OpaquePointer` in Swift 3.

But one significant change you should realize is not the name but the feature which is common to all pointers in Swift 3:

- In Swift 3, pointer types cannot contain `nil`, and if you want to store `nil` to a pointer type variable, you need to declare it as an Optional pointer. ([SE-0055](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0055-optional-unsafe-pointers.md))

So, for the short question:

```
var audioConverter : AudioConverterRef? = nil
audioConverter = nil
```

And for the longer one:

The type `AudioConverterRef` is declared as:

```
typedef struct OpaqueAudioConverter *   AudioConverterRef;
```

And the type `struct OpaqueAudioConverter` is a hidden C-struct. It is not just referencing `AVAudioConverter`, but may be holding some info to work with C-function based AudioConverter APIs. Its properties may be held in more primitive forms than similar properties in `AVAudioConverter`.

You have no need to work with `AudioConverterRef`, if all functionalities you need is available in `AVAudioConverter`.

Comment: Strange thing about OpaquePointer is that the type itself is Optional and requires unboxing, but you can't initialize it to nil unless you declare it Optional. Seems like the compiler does not generate a double Optional, so yes, it's the only way.